# AngularJS ng-repeat Math Pow

Tags: angularjs, math, service, factory, angularjs-ng-repeat

AngularJS noob here. I'm trying to generate a table dynamically when user enters a number in input field, and the table returns 10 rows of expontential values in sequence. For example:

```
<div ng-controller='myController'>
<input type="text" ng-model="number">
<table>
<tr><th>Index</th><th>Number</th>
<tr ng-repeat='item in ebooks'><td>{{$index}}</td><td>{{ item.amt}}</td><td> {{ Math.pow(number, $index+1 }}</td>
<td>{{  Math.pow(number,$index+1) * item.amt   }}</td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

In my Controller, I have a dataset ebooks.

```
app.controller('myController',function($scope) {
$scope.ebooks = [{amt:0.25},{amt:0.10},{amt:0.05},{item:0.02}];
});
```

I am trying to generate the table where the cell Number will display a corresponding exponential number and another column which multiplies the exponential number with item value. I think I should be using Service or Factory, but I don't know what is the right approach. The outcome I want is:

```
 enter number = 5
 Item     Price   Number  Total
  1       0.25    5        1.25
  2       0.1     25        2.5
  3       0.05    125       3.25
```

in my Services I tried doing this:

```
app.service('MathService', function(){
this.Expo = function (a) {return Math(a, $index +1)};
});
```

But it doesn't work that way.

I read some other tutorials about mapping arrays in Factory, but can't understand it.
I think I need to create it in factory by somehow adding the Expo key to the ebooks dataset, so it looks like this {item: value, expo:value}.

Very confused and messed up. Help!

Comment: Try adding $scope.Math = Math; in your controller

Comment: @ZackArgyle's comment should be the answer.  ↑↑↑

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `$filter` instead, like this:

```
.filter('mathPow', function(){
    return function(base, exponent){
        return Math.pow(base, exponent);
    }
})
```

And you can use it like this in your view:

```
<div ng-controller='myController'>
    <input type="text" ng-model="number">
    <table>
        <tr><th>Index</th><th>Number</th></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat='item in ebooks'>
            <td>{{$index}}</td>
            <td>{{ item.amt}}</td>
            <td>{{ number|mathPow:$index+1 }}</td>
            <td>{{ (number|mathPow:($index+1))*item.amt}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/qo2uvwyz/)

Comment: You. Are. A. Genius!
It worked like a charm! Thanks so much. Wow. Didn't know about filter like this. Don't really understand how it worked but will try to understand it with more reading.